# Possible to round down to second decimal place based off 3+ decimal spots in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to figure out how to essentially create a "floor" call based on a specific decimal place as opposed to a whole value. Below is a table of actual values and the desired result:

```
=========|=========
3.125    |  3.12
4.187    |  4.18
1.212    |  1.21
5.999    |  5.99
```

Is this possible with mysql? using the round function to the 2nd decimal place returns "bad" data and rounding to the third does not reach the goal either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [TRUNCATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate):

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(3.125, 2)
```

Output:

```
 3.12
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you multiply by 100 and floor and then divide by 100?  Like

floor(value*100)/100

Comment: MrTippet - your solution works great and i like the concept, just went with OMG Ponies solution because it was a way pass answer (and simple find and replace with my existing round() function)